# UK Spouse Visa: should I disclose speeding tickets and small fines issued in Russia

Tags: visas, uk

When I was applying for a Spouse visa in 2016, the questioning was a bit different: it clearly stated **criminal offense**. I answered I had no penalties and got the visa.
Now the wording is: At any time have you ever had any of the following, in the UK or in another country?.. A caution, warning, reprimand or other penalties

Because it no longer mentions "criminal", I am not sure whether I need to disclose my penalties.

Please advice!

Some background information:

I have been driving in Russia for 10 years and got multiple speeding tickets (which I paid and never saved a copy of). I also believe I have been issued tickets for crossing the road in the wrong place as a pedestrian, having dirty car number plate etc.

I don't think any of it is considered a criminal offense in Russia, as only drunk driving, extreme speeding (up to 60km/h) etc leads to police revoking your driver's license for a period of time. Everything else is just a fine - we have no points-based system here.

- All the speeding tickets were issued in my gran's name, as the car is registered on her
- Some of the small tickets (mentioned above) were issued in my name